# Django - AJAX Fetch sends request for each input letter

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

This might be far from how it should be done, I'm learning on the go and it's my first time trying something like this.

Problem: **Even with the setTimeout function, server sends response for each letter I have written, though I would expect it to wait for user to stop typing and just fetch the finished word(s)**

**Script in my template:**

```
lookup.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
    
    let searchValue = e.target.value;

    if (searchValue.length > 4){

      setTimeout(() => {
     
        fetch(`{% url 'find_book' %}?param=${e.target.value}` )
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => console.log(data))
          .catch(err => console.log(err))}, 2000);
        }
```

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def find_book(request):

    param = request.GET.get("param")

    if param:
        url = f'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=intitle:{param}&key=xxx'
        r = requests.get(url)
        
        if r.status_code == 200:
            data = r.json()
            return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({"error": "Request failed"}, status=r.status_code)
    else:
        return Response({}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: So a setTimeout will not prevent requests from happening.  It will only delay them.  Further more, your example doesn't show the delay you are giving to the timeout, so it could be happening immediately.  Typically when you are doing this type of logic you are looking to "debounce" or "throttle" logic.  Which means, you create a timeout that last for say `300` milliseconds.  If you get another attempt within those 300 milliseconds, you cancel the previous timeout and start a new one.  That way, the only one that happens is the last one that happens after 300 milliseconds of no activity

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. I'm not sure which delay you mean, but only one that comes to mind is from the timeout function itself, which is 2000. So if I understand correctly, I should just decrease this time to 300ms? Or is there any other delay, which you are mentioning? Also, is this method of using setTimeout function even good option, or is there cleaner and more relevant way?

Comment: If you have the timeout set to 2000, that's fine.  You just need to cancel the timeout, if it exists, every time before you create a new one.  That will result in timeouts that have not reached 2000 yet from finishing if you create a new one

Comment: I only mentioned 300 because, iirc, that's like the delay range that plugins like bootstrap use.  So I try to keep things fairly similar.

Comment: Yes, seems like inserting condition before the settimeout helped. Thank you for explaining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store timeout id to variable in the scope higher than yours event listner.
When event fires up - check if there was a timeout and clear it (which means cancel the request if it wasn't yet executed)

Example:

```
let delayedFetch;

lookup.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
    
    let searchValue = e.target.value;

    if (searchValue.length > 4){

      if (delayedFetch) clearTimeout(delayedFetch);

      delayedFetch = setTimeout(() => {
     
        fetch(`{% url 'find_book' %}?param=${e.target.value}` )
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => console.log(data))
          .catch(err => console.log(err))}, 2000);
        }
```

Comment: The answer has the same issue as the OP, in that the `setTimeout` is not properly closed and does not have a delay given to it.  The event listener method is also unclosed.

Comment: Both snippets have `setTimeout` and event listener function closed. They just don’t have proper line breaks and indents. I just kept questions format for its author to see the change.

Comment: Ooooh, I see, the `console.log(err))}, 2000);` part has a bunch of closing parts that are not formatted to match up with the indentation.  So it is properly closed up to the `if` for the searchValue.length.  The event listener though is definitely not properly closed